# Decimal number doesn't save decimal places in .net

Tags: .net, decimal

I am reading SOA webservice which returns value in decimal format. The requirement is whatever the service returns we need to display the value as it is (including decimal places). The issue i am running into is, whenever there 0 value after the decimal places after casting the 0 decimal places gets removed. e.g. in decimal1 and decimal3, it will return 123 and 123.1 getting rid of last decimal place.

```
decimal decimal1 =  (decimal) 123.00;  --returns 123
decimal decimal2 = (decimal) 123.01;   --returns 123.01
decimal decimal3 = (decimal) 123.10;   --returns 123.1
```

Is there any way i can have the decimal place without loosing the 0 value at the end? The end data type has to be decimal (or numeric value) and cannot be string. 
Thanks

Sanjeev

Comment: The act of displaying your decimal implies a conversion to a string.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that `123.10` is a `double`, and `double`s don't retain precision information like `decimal`s do.

So the underlying representation of `123.10` is equal to `123.1`.
==> **The cast to `decimal` happens too late**.

The solution is to declare a `decimal` literal in your source code by using the `m` suffix.

```
var decimal1 = 123m;
var decimal2 = 123.10m;

decimal1.ToString() // gives "123";
decimal2.ToString() // gives "123.10";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain digits then you need to convert from string:

```
Convert.ToDecimal("1.10")
Convert.ToDecimal("1.1")
```

Because it is float who is not keeping them.

Float doesn't "remember" decimal digits. During compilation time all decimal float literals are converted to their binary counterparts and decimal 0-s are lost:

```
csharp> BitConverter.GetBytes(1.1)
{ 154, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 241, 63 }
csharp> BitConverter.GetBytes(1.10)
{ 154, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 241, 63 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are worried about here is how the decimal is formatted into a `string`, you can control this with the various overrides of [`.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx).  The "data' of the `decimal` value remains intact regardless of how it's output as a string.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned a decimal is a value type that does not care about how its formatted, it cares about how it persists an accurate decimal. Representing the decimal as a human readable string should be handled by the presentation layer and in that layer the decimal should be converted from the type decimal to a string type. Here you can format the decimal so it is displayed (as a string) with XX values after the decimal, is rounded, with a `.` as the separator or a `,' depending on the culture of your user, etc.

See the Microsoft [Standard Numeric Formats Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) web site which shows many of the built existing ways that you can use to format a decimal (among other types).

What you will need to do is use the N / Number format specifier.

```
decimal decimal1 =  123M;
var myFormattedString = decimal1.ToString("N2");
```